# Load SnackBar before navigating to login page

Tags: flutter, mobile-development, flutter-navigation, flutter-form-builder

I have a signup form and I am trying to make it show the successful SnackBar message first before it navigates to the login page. when I add it to my if statement, it just pushes the login screen without showing any of the Snackbar messages

```
                   onPressed: ()  {
    
                        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            content: Text('processing data'),
                          ));

                          User user = User(
                            fullName: fullName.text,
                            phoneNumber: phoneNumber.text,
                            password: password.text,
                          );

                          final database = DatabaseProvider.db;
                          database.insert(user);
                         
                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            content: Text('registration successful'),
                          ));

                       Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, Routes.home);
                        }

                        _formKey.currentState.save();
                      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me. Chained `.closed` and `.then` to the snackbar

```
onPressed: () {
                        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            content: Text('processing data'),
                          ));

                          User user = User(
                            fullName: fullName.text,
                            phoneNumber: phoneNumber.text,
                            password: password.text,
                          );

                          final database = DatabaseProvider.db;
                          database.insert(user);

                          Scaffold.of(context)
                              .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                content: Text('registration successful'),
                              ))
                              .closed
                              .then((value) => Navigator.popAndPushNamed(
                                  context, Routes.home));
                        }

                        _formKey.currentState.save();
                      },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
onPressed: () async {

                    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                      await Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                        content: Text('processing data'),
                      ));

                      User user = User(
                        fullName: fullName.text,
                        phoneNumber: phoneNumber.text,
                        password: password.text,
                      );

                      final database = DatabaseProvider.db;
                      await database.insert(user);
                     
                      await Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                        content: Text('registration successful'),
                      ));

                   Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, Routes.home);
                    }

                    _formKey.currentState.save();
                  },
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution, someone suggested I use the .then and close method on snack bar which worked, using await didn't work when I tried it